# Is there a python function for auto filling NULL values for numeric & object columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is an efficient way of auto-filling null values for the categorical columns and numeric columns in a dataframe with python?

So far I'm using the below function for filling null values to the categorical columns and numeric columns.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dictdf = {"Num1": [111, 222, 444, np.nan, 666, 222],
          "Obj1": ["a", np.nan, "b", "c", "d", np.nan],
          "Num2": [np.nan, 247, 321, np.nan, 654, 212],
          "Obj2": ["cdb", np.nan, np.nan, "kbc", "kdd", "np"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictdf)

df
```

```
     Num1   Obj1    Num2    Obj2
0   111.0   a        NaN    cdb
1   222.0   NaN     247.0   NaN
2   444.0   b       321.0   NaN
3   NaN     c        NaN    kbc
4   666.0   d       654.0   kdd
5   222.0   NaN     212.0   np
```

```
def autoFillNA(df):

    object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns)
    numeric_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns)

    if (df[object_cols].isnull().sum().sum()) > 1:
        df[object_cols].astype(object)
        df[object_cols] = df[object_cols].fillna('Missing')

    if (df[numeric_cols].isnull().sum().sum()) > 1:
        df[numeric_cols] = df[numeric_cols].fillna(-999)
    
    return df

autoFillNA(df)
```

Output:

```
    Num1    Obj1    Num2    Obj2
0   111.0   a      -999.0   cdb
1   222.0   Missing 247.0   Missing
2   444.0   b       321.0   Missing
3   -999.0  c      -999.0   kbc
4   666.0   d       654.0   kdd
5   222.0   Missing 212.0   np
```

I'm looking for an efficient and better approach to do this for sample or large datasets. Any suggestions or references would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary of all columns for replace:

```
d1 = dict.fromkeys(df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns, -999)
d2 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(d1.keys()), 'Missing')
#merge both dicts
d = {**d1, **d2}

df = df.fillna(d)
#or with one dict
#df = df.fillna(d1).fillna('Missing')
print (df)
    Num1     Obj1   Num2     Obj2
0  111.0        a -999.0      cdb
1  222.0  Missing  247.0  Missing
2  444.0        b  321.0  Missing
3 -999.0        c -999.0      kbc
4  666.0        d  654.0      kdd
5  222.0  Missing  212.0       np
```

Also if want test only columns with missing values:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.isna().sum().gt(0)]
d1 = dict.fromkeys(df1.select_dtypes(np.number).columns, -999)
d2 = dict.fromkeys(df1.columns.difference(d1.keys()), 'Missing')
d = {**d1, **d2}

df = df.fillna(d)
```

---

Similar idea like your solution:

```
c = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns

df[c] = df[c].fillna(-999)
df = df.fillna('Missing')
print (df)
    Num1     Obj1   Num2     Obj2
0  111.0        a -999.0      cdb
1  222.0  Missing  247.0  Missing
2  444.0        b  321.0  Missing
3 -999.0        c -999.0      kbc
4  666.0        d  654.0      kdd
5  222.0  Missing  212.0       np
```

Comment: First, Fast, Simple, and Precise in Answering...!! U r Amazing

Answer (score 0):

Try the Pandas DataFrame fillna function for each column

```
df['Num1'] = df['Num1'].fillna(-999)
df['Num2'] = df['Num2'].fillna(-999)
df['Obj1'] = df['Obj1'].fillna("Missing")
df['Obj2'] = df['Obj2'].fillna("Missing")
```

Comment: What if I have 100 columns??